# Is there a way to bind a handler to browser history back button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, browser-history

For example the user came to the page from `example.com/home.html` to the page `example.com/checkout.html`. I wonder if there is a way to assign a history back to something like `example.com/new_offers.html`?

So, when clicking his browser back button, instead of going to `home.html` the user will be redirected to `new_offers.html`

I know it may sound awkward, but it's just the example and the thing I need this for is a bit different. Also, I need to do this using JavaScript only (nothing server-side).

#### UPD: I figured out that it'd be clearer to ask whether it's possible to bind a handler to browser back button like (jQuery):

`$(browser.backButton).click(function(e){ ... })`

Comment: i have a bad feeling about your intentions...

Comment: @fazo: why are you worried about his intentions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of going to the **checkout** page from the **home** page, you can go to **new_offers**, which checks a variable `checked_out`. If `checked_out` is false, then redirect the user to **checkout** passing along all the form information. If `checked_out` was true, then display the **new_offers** page.
`checked_out` will be set to true at the **checkout** page.

In this way, if the user clicks back at the **checkout** page, the user will actually go to the **new_offers** page.

I don't like this design very much as it means that a user has to click back twice quickly to get to a previous website, but it does satisfy your goals.

In other words, your current design does this:

home --> checkout

Instead, do this:

home --> new_offers -- (redirect) --> checkout

So that new_offers redirects to checkout immediately unless it sees that the user has already checked out.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, excuse me for a bit blurry example. Have edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Only thing I would add to this answer is that you really should not be doing this. You should not be manually manipulating the back button. If the user clicks back, they should be taken to the page they were at previously. If you want another mechanism, you should put a "Back" button or link somewhere on your site that will take them where you want them to go.

Comment: @Idris Mokhtarzada that was just the thing I was explaining to the client. I will quote you if I fail to find a solution.

Comment: @Idris, absolutely I agree and that's why I mentioned that "I don't like this design very much [...]". I'm glad that you said it here more explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've modified your question to be about jQuery, you can use this jQuery plugin to solve this issue:

http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Give this a read.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: It's not clear to me whether there is a function to replace the previous history entry.

Comment: I believe you can only change the current entry, alteration of other entries may be a problem for security reasons.